# Is it possible to create a view to show a field from a user acc and content?

Tags: views

when i create a view in Drupal7 i have to choose what i want to display ( like Users, Content, Terms ... ) .

Is it possible to choose Users and Content?

My problem is:

I have a geofield field in the User Account and in 2 content types. I need a view where i can display this field from all Nodes and Users in one view.

Has someone a trick or a solution for this? I can't find anything about this...

Thanks Flo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two drupal views with different base types ('user' and 'node')](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15180/merge-two-drupal-views-with-different-base-types-user-and-node)

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to link the user account some how to content which i assume could be possible using  $node_author, you also need to connect both the contents with each other using reference field.

In drupal view you can use Relationships tab which available above the Arguments in the center colum of the view add/edit form. To learn about Using View's relationship pleases refer to How To: [Using View's Relationships](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-relationships)